# Strange error when import DB into PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, export

I tryed to import one database from one host to another, but got this error when try to import to destination server:

```
Error
Static analysis:

18795 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 6832)
Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 6835)
Unexpected character. (near "{" at position 6836)
Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 6838)
Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 6842)
Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 6846)
Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 6964)
Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 6968)
Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 6972)
Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 7079)
Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 7083)
Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 7087)
Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 7196)
Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 7200)
Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 7203)
```

and continue....

What i tryed:

- Exported gziped database and tryed to import -> without success.
- Tryed to uncheck "Enclose table and column names with backquotes (Protects column and table names formed with special characters or keywords)" before export, also without success.

The Phpmyadmin version that i trying to import database is version: 4.5.0.2 and version from where i get database backup have version 4.0.10.14.

Can someone to help me with this issue?

Comment: Its probably more relevant to quote the MYSQL versions, but having said that `phpMyAdmin` did have some wierd issues with importing/exporting in versions around 4.0 so that may be the issue. Can you not use `mysqldump` on the source server?

Comment: How to use mysqldump ?

Comment: Well you [look at the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html)

Comment: I dont have access to shell..

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar issue when trying to import a database backup from the same host into the phpMyAdmin. Since the report mentioned first errors around some linebreaks I figured it had to be something with encoding (still all files were utf-8).

When I simply imported unpacked .sql file all was fine, so this must be some bug in the on-the-fly unpacker in phpMyAdmin (v.4.8.5 in my case).